# how to display values in html after we extract data from url

Tags: javascript, html

I'm testing a requirement where data will be entered in `test1.html` and click submit. I get query parameters to another html called `test2.html` in an url. Now after reading the url data, i need to display values. I'm able to extract data but how to show in html body?

### URL i'm getting in `test2.html`.

`file:///D:/test/testing/test2.html?UserFirstName=aa&UserLastName=bb&bday=2020-01-21&Status=consultant&vendorFirstName=aaa&vendorLastName=ccc&employerFirstName=bbb&employerLastName=ddd`

### javascript and html code in test2.html  - Tried this and its not displaying values. Any help?

```
<html>
<body>
<script>

urlp=[];
s=location.toString().split('?');
s=s[1].split('&');
for(i=0;i<s.length;i++)
{
    u=s[i].split('=');
    urlp[u[0]]=u[1];
};

var userfirstname=urlp['UserFirstName'];
var userlastname=urlp['UserlastName'];
var vendorfirstname=urlp['vendorFirstName'];
var vendorlastname=urlp['vendorLastName'];

</script>

<div class="tree">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#">userfirstname</a>                
                <a href="#">userlastname</a>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">vendorfirstname</a>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">vendorlastname</a>
                        </li>
                    </li>  
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're not using those variables inside a `<script>` tag, therefore the browser just sees them as plain text. You need to write javascript code that will set the [innerText](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_innertext.asp) property of those links. Give them some ids so you can get them with `document.getElementById(id)`.

Comment: I have two htmls. In first html, user enters firstname, last name, status, vendor details, employer deails and click submit. In second html, I get the values in url. I read those values in second html and show them in tree structure based on status.  The code and details i mentioned are from second html. Please let me know based on thsi req.

Comment: Your error is in the 2nd html, in the code you have shown. Please read my comment again closely and open the innerText link I gave you. That link explains what you need to do to fix this error.

Comment: It's a security risk to put content that a user passes in directly on the page. It's called Cross Site Scripting or XSS, and there are many approaches to reducing the risk. To see if you code is subject, try passing in `<script>alert('xss')</script>` as your username.

Comment: @GrahamPHeath, This is a prototype only. Actual project will have every security aspect covered.

Answer (score 1):

You're just assigning it to a variable, not actually placing it on the `DOM`. You need to do some DOM operations for it.
First give an id to the elements where you want the value to go:

```html
<div class="tree">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a id="userFirstName" href="#"></a>                
                <a id="userLastName" href="#"></a>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a id="vendorFirstName" href="#"></a>
                        <li>
                            <a id="vendorLastName" href="#"></a>
                        </li>
                    </li>  
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Then get those elements with the `document` object method `getElementById`:

```
const userFirstNameElement = document.getElementById('userFirstName');
const userLastNameElement = document.getElementById('userLastName');

const vendorFirstNameElement = document.getElementById('vendorFirstName');
const vendorFirstNameElement = document.getElementById('vendorLastName');
```

Then give them a value of what you desire:

```
var userfirstname=urlp['UserFirstName'];
var userlastname=urlp['UserlastName'];
var vendorfirstname=urlp['vendorFirstName'];
var vendorlastname=urlp['vendorLastName'];

userFirstNameElement.innerHTML = userfirstname;
userLastNameElement.innerHTML = userlastname;
vendorFirstNameElement.innerHTML = vendorfirstname;
vendorLastNameElement.innerHTML = vendorlastname;
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I have two htmls. In first html, user enters firstname, last name, status, vendor details, employer deails and click submit. In second html, I get the values in url. I read those values in second html and show them in tree structure based on status.  The code and details i mentioned are from second html. Please let me know based on thsi req.

Comment: Its still the same process, after you get it from the querystring in the url you need to place it in the dom by following the process I mentioned. By getting the value of the variables as `innerHTML` of the elements you want.

Comment: how do you display innerHTML values in html tags under body?

Comment: Please read my second instruction, you get the elements via `document.getElementById` notice that I gave the elements where you want to place the value an `id` attribute so that you could select them. After you can set their values (the variable where your holding the result of `document.getElementById()`) and assign their `innerHTML` to the values you want.